# JSF LInk to View Page

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, managed-bean

I have a page with a data table.  I want some of the items in the tables to be linked to a corresponding view page.

For example, right now I have a table with no links:

```
<h:dataTable var="bean" value="#{beanServiceImpl.beans}" border="1">
    <h:column>#{bean.id}</h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
```

I want to add hyperlinks to some entries and have them go to a view page showing them more info based on their id:

```
  <h:dataTable var="bean" value="#{beanServiceImpl.beans}" border="1">
    <h:column>
        <a href="viewBean.xhtml?id=#{bean.id}">#{bean.id}</a>
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
```

ViewBean.xhtml will contain something like this:

ViewBean.xhtml

```
<ul>
  <li>ID: #{bean.id}</li>
  <li>Field 1: #{bean.field1}</li>
  <li>Field 2: #{bean.field2}</li>
</ul>
```

How do I accomplish something like this in JSF?  I know that I'll have to write a controller to query the id for the other fields.  But how do I make viewBean.xhtml run the business logic to get the other fields and render it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The BalusC's answer is almost good, but will not work (**edit:** it works now).

You already know, how to add the value to the params. BTW, if I were you, I would not use `<a href>`,  but instead:

```
<h:link outcome='viewBean'>
    <f:param name='id' value='#{bean.id}' />
</h:link>
```

Now you have to choices when it comes to catching the value. The simplest would be to add annotation above your id property:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.id}") // this will inject id from param into id
private Long id;


//  (getters and setters are obligatory)


@PostConstruct // this will execute init() after id is injected
public void init() {

}
```

And the last thing: having a variable named "bean" has no more sense than calling it "variable" (or having a dog named Dog and cat named Cat). It carries no information and worse, it makes all the beans in your application indistinguishable (unless you build a legumes manager).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1  As for the variable named "Bean", I just renamed it to make it more generic so I can post as an example (even field1 and field2 were generic). I'm pretty new to SO but I assume this is proper when asking programming questions in any public forum. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume JSF 2.x. Add this to your `Bean`

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")
private Long id;
```

*(this does basically a `bean.setId(request.getParameter("id"))` whenever the view loads)*

It'll be available in `@PostConstruct` method of `Bean`.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // Fill model based on id.
}
```

Comment: Uhm. The answer is plain wrong - view parameters are part of the standard faces lifecycle, so any values from the request will NOT be available when @PostConstruct is called. We need to wait untill model values are updated.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks for your answer.  I posted my solution below because I think we might have addressed different things.

Comment: You're now firing a POST request (form with fake-link) instead of a GET request (link). That's entirely different from what you initially asked. But if the functional requirement is indeed to fire a POST request, then go ahead with yours. You only won't ever be able to call it by http://example.com/viewbean.xhtml?id=1 (i.e. it is not bookmarkable).

Comment: I am not one to complain (well, I lied - I am complaining badly right now, just ignore me) but BalusC answer was wrong and fixed only after I posted mine - to an identical one. Yet, I don't get the juicy 15 points that would constitute almost 1% of my current status. And BalusC's answer is marked, which advances him about 0.00000001% of what he's already got. Woe is me...

Comment: @fdr: Do you feel now better with twice as much points? :) You were entirely right that I was initially wrong as to setting the value (it was late yesterday tonight). But a wrong answer needs to be fixed anyway. Don't misinterpret me, you're more than welcome here. JSF tag needs more good folks.

Comment: @BalusC: much better, although slightly ashamed of myself :-) sorry for whining, I hope to make up for it.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did.

```
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink action="#{bean.populateBean}" value="#{bean.id}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.id}" value="#{bean.id}" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
```

In my Bean.java class, I added the action controller:

```
public String populateBean(){
    Bean bean = BeanServiceImpl.getBean(id); //id was injected by the commandLink
    this.field1 = tenure.getField1();
    this.field2 = tenure.getField2();

    return("viewBean");
}
```

My ViewBean.xhtml is the same:

```
<ul>
  <li>ID: #{bean.id}</li>
  <li>Field 1: #{bean.field1}</li>
  <li>Field 2: #{bean.field2}</li>
</ul>
```